# MySQL - Add extra column in the final output based on the value of a relation table

Tags: php, mysql

It's been a while since I have worked with MySQL and cannot figure this out by myself: I have three tables, one for `users`, one for `books` and one for `favourites`. I'm developing a search system where user can search for books based on their title, publish year or genre.

There isn't really anything fancy about the `books` nor the `users` table so I thought it is irrelevant to post the schemas of neither of these tables.
The `favourites` table is a relation table consisting two `foreign key` columns for both, book_id and user_id.

My objective is to run a query that fetches all the books based on the search query but will also seek the `favourites` table and if user has added that particular book into his/her favorites, then adds an extra column to the final output, f.e `isFavorable: 0`, otherwise: `isFavorable: 1`. The final output would look something like this (in `JSON`format):

```
{
  data: [
    {
      // non favorite
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Test Book 1",
      "genre": "Adventure",
      "year": 1994,
      "isFavorite": 0 // if cannot be found in the favourites table
    },

    // favorite
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Test Book 2",
      "genre": "Novel"
      "year": 2012,
      "isFavorite": 1 // if can be found in the favorites table
    }
  ]
}
```

So far, I've only been able to output all the results that are marked as favorites, instead of all the books and cannot figure out how to check if it's already been marked as a favourite and output an correspondig value.

This will print all the books user #1 has liked

```
SELECT * FROM books b 
LEFT JOIN favourites f ON f.book_id = b.id 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = f.user_id 
WHERE u.id = 1
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` should be `RIGHT JOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with:

```
SELECT
 b.id
 , b.title
 , b.year
 , b.genre
 , IF(f.book_id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS isFavorite 
FROM books b 
LEFT JOIN favourites f ON f.book_id = b.id AND f.user_id = 1
WHERE
 ... e.g. b.year = 3099 AND b.genre = 'Sport'
```

1. remove `users` table since you only need the `user_id` from `favorites`
2. move the condition from the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause since you also want to have the not (yet) liked books
3. use a `IF` statement to determine if your user already liked the book

Comment: Thanks, it was just exactly what I needed. Cheers, mate :)